# Alexa app to app account linking in android app , Skill Activation Api gives error

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

here is the link

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/app-to-app-account-linking-starting-from-your-app.html

Steps that I followed in my Android App.

I completed the LWA fallback url setup , in fallback URL I have used client ID that is received from Account linking page of Alexa custom skill.

After open the LWA url in browser , page asked to Login in Amazon after that I can see the page where my skill asked to access the lwa details with an Allow and Cancel button

After Allow My Application is getting Auth-Token , From that Auth-Token I am calling token API and getting Access Token.

after that I am calling below activation skill api

```
POST /v1/users/~current/skills/{skillId}/enablement HTTP/1.1
Host: api.amazonalexa.com, api.eu.amazonalexa.com, 
api.fe.amazonalexa.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: "Bearer {Amazon Access Token}"
{
    "stage": "skill stage",
    "accountLinkRequest": {
    "redirectUri": "https://yourRedirectURI",
    "authCode": "Your user's authorization code from your authorization 
server",
  "type": "AUTH_CODE"
}
}
```

I have used parameters values like below

```
Amazon access token - Got that from Amazon token API.
redirectUri = https://pitangui.amazon.com/api/skill/link/XXXXXXXXXXX
authCode = got after perform successful login with amazon.
```

But I got 400 bad request error with Message

```
{"message":"Invalid account linking credentials"}
```

I am not able to get what I am doing wrong . Help me out if anyone have some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The  400 bad request "Invalid account linking credentials" it's because you are receiving wrong credentials, so make sure that you are using correct client ID and secret to use skill Activation API.

I would recommend following this article.
https://amazon.developer.forums.answerhub.com/articles/240817/app-to-app-account-linking-debugging-tips.html